# Bug in my script, click on same thumbnail twice it wont work

Tags: jquery

If i click on the same thumb twice the image fades out but then never fades back in. initially i would like it so when the thumb is active it is not selectable if possible.
Any help would be great, thanks.

Here is my jsfiddle of what i am talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/vAzSn/5/

```
$('.thumbs ul li').css('opacity', '.5');
$('.thumbs ul li:first-child').addClass('current');
$('.projectview').children().hide();
$('.projectview').children("section").first().show();
$('.thumbs ul li').click(function () {
    // Show info
    var thumb = $(this).attr('class');
    var partner = $('.' + thumb + 'info');
    $('.projectview').children().fadeOut();
    partner.fadeIn();
    // Tab opacity
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vAzSn/8/)**. I just added a check in your click event,

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {...
```

New jQuery:

```
$('.thumbs ul li').css('opacity', '.5');
$('.thumbs ul li:first-child').addClass('current');
$('.projectview').children().hide();
$('.projectview').children(".planinfo").show();
$('.thumbs ul li').click(function () {
    // Show info
    if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
        var thumb = $(this).attr('class');
        var partner = $('.' + thumb + 'info');
        $('.projectview').children().fadeOut();
        partner.fadeIn();
        // Tab opacity
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Comment: Just imported it into my script and it has no effect on it. Worked perfect on the jsfiddle. Little confused on why it would do this. Did you add anything else?

Comment: Did you check your console to see if there were any errors? Do you have other code that wasn't in your example?

Comment: Hmmm, no errors and no other conflicting code? Seems odd. All it was was a simple new if statement. I'm assuming you remembered the closing `}` for the if.

Comment: I am going to go through my scripts and see if any of them are conflicting. the class .'current' seems like it would be a popular name to use

Comment: when you click on a thumbnail it adds the class .current and displays the relevant div below. if you click on that same thumbnail link twice in a row it does not remove the class .current, and it fades the relevant image below out, when you try clicking on it the third time in a row it will not let you click it and performs nothing.

Comment: So the question is why does it let you click on it a second time when it already has the class .current?

Comment: Are you saying it does that in the fiddle or your code, because I'm not seeing that behavior in the fiddle.

Comment: Figured it out, thank for the help. your script was fine as i expected.